# How do I use typeclasses in Haskell functions?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-declaration

I'm currently trying to teach myself Haskell with Learn You A Haskell, and so to test myself I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of numbers and returns the average value.

```
listlen :: [a] -> Int
listlen [] = 0
listlen (x:xs) = 1 + listlen xs

avg :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
avg [] = error "Cannot average list of length 0"
avg l = ((foldr (+) 0 l) `div` (listlen l))

main = putStrLn (show (avg [1,2,3,4,5]))
```

However, when I run this code, I get this error message:

```
test.hs:7:10: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          avg :: forall a. Num a => [Int] -> a
        at test.hs:5:8
    • In the expression: ((foldr (+) 0 l) `div` (listlen l))
          In an equation for ‘avg’:
          avg l = ((foldr (+) 0 l) `div` (listlen l))
    • Relevant bindings include
        avg :: [Int] -> a (bound at test.hs:6:1)
```

I've been tinkering with the signature and the only way I can get it to work is to make the types into actual types, e.g. `avg :: [Int] -> Int`. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from here:

```
avg l = ((foldr (+) 0 l) `div` (listlen l))
```

`div` is defined over `Integral`s, not just `Num`s. Also, `div` floors the result. Normal division is `(/)`, which is defined over `Fractional`s.

Also (more directly) from here:

```
listlen :: [a] -> Int
listlen [] = 0
listlen (x:xs) = 1 + listlen xs
```

`listlen` returns `Int`, which makes `div` have type of `Int -> Int -> Int`.

This should work:

```
listlen :: (Num n) => [a] -> n
listlen [] = 0
listlen (x:xs) = 1 + listlen xs

avg :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
avg [] = error "Cannot average list of length 0"
avg l = foldr (+) 0 l / listlen l
```

Or, with some functions from `Prelude`:

```
avg :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
avg [] = error "Cannot average list of length 0"
avg l = sum l / fromIntegral (length l)
```

Comment: Did you test this solution?

Comment: I just tried the fixed code but I'm still getting a similar error.

Comment: `length` returns an `Int`. I think you haven't learned your lesson about testing yet. ;-)

Comment: Oh my... >_>;;;